# From Typescript to Javascript => required is not defined in chrome browser

Tags: typescript, requirejs, angular

From:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
```

To:

```
var core_1 = require('angular2/core');
```

I get in my browser some errors:

```
required is not defined
```

Why do I have to include requireJS as a runtime dependency? The angular 2 5 min tutorial does not anywhere include that library!

Thats annoying!

https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

When I do:

```
    <script src="~/lib/require.js"></script>
```

I still get the error because of my compiled javascript:

[image]

**UPDATE**

These are the includes script in my header-tag:

```
  <script src="~/lib/es6-shim.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/es6-promise.js"></script>

    <script src="~/lib/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/system.js"></script>

    <script src="~/lib/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/angular2.js"></script>

    <script src="~/lib/http.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/router.dev.js"></script>

    <script asp-src-include="~/app/**/*.js"></script>

    <script>
            System.config({
                packages: {
                    app: {
                        format: 'register',
                        defaultExtension: 'js'
                    }
                }
            });
            System.import('app/main')
                  .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
```

**UPDATE 2**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `SystemJS`, requirejs is not required (;

You might have an issue with loading bundles from `node_modules` folder, if that's the case (check Devtools > Network), try using CDN versions:

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/http.min.js"></script>
```

#### UPDATE:

You are trying to manually load your script. You should let `SystemJS` do it, just remove:

```
<script asp-src-include="~/app/**/*.js"></script>
```

and it should work...

Comment: What's your index.html like?

Comment: It did not help. But I am also not sure wether it helps when I outcomment the usage of my source scripts... - serious question - Of course the error is gone now because my scripts are gone now... Even if you are right, there is one last 'require is undefined' error see screenshot!

Comment: A big LOL to myself...Really I am just learning TS,Angular2 etc... I just read a tutorial where someone used module:system in the tsconfig.json where I used commonJS HAHA no wonder the js output did not work :P So finally you was right about removing my include *.js